# Fault Lines in North America

Tags: geography

I was trying to figure out what areas in North America would be most likely to have earthquakes, but I couldn't come across a good map for this. It's easy to find the areas with the highest incidence of hurricanes and tornadoes, and I know California has a high rate of earthquakes. What fault lines are there in North America (besides the obvious San Andreas fault)? Are there any maps that clearly show this?

Comment: There are very few places in the U.S. where there aren't faults. Please read up on faults ([like this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_(geology))) and try to narrow the focus of your question. Here's [an interactive map of just the most recent active faults](http://usgs.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=db287853794f4555b8e93e42290e9716).

Comment: I must say, I was pretty useless at finding a good map of major faults in NA, so maybe it's less obvious than it sounds.  Stephanie, it does appear that there are a ton of faults out there, though, as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:California_Faults shows

Comment: To ad red to @Spencer's comment. Some faults in the US have been reactivated by fracking. Regions that rarely experienced earth quakes, now experience quakes since fracking commenced in & near those areas

Comment: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/qfaults/map/#qfaults

Comment: I reopened this question as @JeopardyTempest makes a good point that a map of this is hard to come by.

Comment: Ty for all these infos.. I have alot to look thru .. Something for me to learn more ..

Answer (score 3):

Here is a map of seismic hazards for the United States from the United States Geological Survey. [Link](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/hazmaps/).

[image: Seismic hazard map for the lower US]

[Link](http://usgs.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=db287853794f4555b8e93e42290e9716) to interactive fault map for the US (source: USGS)
Here is a [link](https://www.wired.com/2008/10/five-us-earthqu/) to a nice article on top 5 earthquake prone areas outside California.

It is presence of fault zones, geological structures (like volcanos, subduction zones, tectonic plate junctions, basins, and mountains), geological evidence of past events, and record of earthquake events that go into the calculation of a seismic hazard for a specific region.

Comment: to add, that nasty red bump in the center is right on the new madrid fault zone which is responsible for one of the worst earthquake in US history.  Worse it likes to drop swarms not single events. Alaska has somnastier ones though, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1964_Alaska_earthquake

Comment: Here is a similar map for all of north america not just the US.https://i.pinimg.com/474x/99/50/df/9950df23f297cd0eefd80fbe04b5a7fa--earthquake-fault-north-america.jpg

Comment: Ty for the infos .. I have alot to look over and see where most are located..  Tysvm

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few links that may help out with your question:

- https://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/qfaults/map/#qfaults
- http://www.cbc.ca/beta/news/multimedia/every-fault-line-in-british-columbia-1.2919420